# Flex hot deployment for local tomcat server

Tags: apache-flex, tomcat7, flex4

I am working on flex application and whenever I do any change in action scripts or mxml file I'll have to build it create a war file and deploy it on local tomcat server. Is there any way I could do hot deployment for flex for tomcat?

Thanks
Sach

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom Builder if you are using Flash Builder.
I'm using a simple batch file that copies the output from `bin-debug` to Tomcat's `webapps` folder after every build.

```
@ECHO OFF

IF NOT EXIST "%1" GOTO END
IF NOT EXIST "%2" GOTO END

DEL /Q "%2\*.*"
COPY /Y "%1\*.*" "%2"

:END
ECHO ON
```

Configure the Builder like this:
Go to *Project* -> *Properties* -> *Builders* and add a new Builder.

[image: Configure the Builder]
[image: Change when the Builder should run]

Comment: Thanks Gerhard. Sorry after long time I replied on this. How this will work if there is any change in Flex MXML or action script file as these file goes as part of SWF file. SWF file update means to restart tomcat correct.

Comment: You have to compile the SWF in Flash Builder when you change a MXML or ActionScript file. The custom `copy-to-webapp` builder wil run after the build and copies the swf to your webapp's directory inside of Tomcat. All you have to do is configure the path to your webapp (screenshot 1).

Comment: I followed these steps but Tomcat is not picking up the changes does in swf file without restarting it. I'll have to restart tomcat for any mxml and action script changes.

Comment: Does anybody aware if tomcat can pick up the flex mxml and action scripts changes with out restarting it?

Comment: Does the batch file work? Did you check that it is copying the SWF to the right location every time you build your Flex application? If it works then it could be a browser caching problem. You'll probably need to set the `Cache-Control` header for your SWF. This definitely should work. I'm using it myself.